# html file downloaded from webpage - content missing if .html is viewed in browser - possibly ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

Overview:

After viewing a webpage online (using Firefox), I saved the webpage to an .html file. Upon then viewing the saved html file in Firefox, much of the content is just not there: I basically just see what amounts to a header and footer. The content I am actually interested in is not displayed.  However, when I use an editor to look at the .html file, I can find the content among the html code fine. I just doesn't show up when I view the page and I can't figure out why. I am wondering how I could alter the code in order for the full page to display.

Specifics:

The webpage I am trying to view is for a recipe (http://www.cooksillustrated.com/recipes/1). This website requires a paid login, so you will likely not see the entire page anyway.

This link has a zip file of the .html file and the folder with the other images and stuff - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7IvODgWvxBbc1EwcmFwa050REE. The .html file has some name/email info in it but I have replaced it with made up info.

The relevant part of the .html file that does not view is **lines 395 to 408**. All the parts of recipe are right there, but it does not display in a browser. (I tried to display these html lines inline, but it exceeds the 30000 character limit.)

This makes me think that something (with which I am not familiar) in the html code is preventing viewing that content, and, if it were deleted or altered, would solve my problem. I have tried searching the web for an answer, but came up empty (I was not not really sure what to ask). And I have very little experience with html to know much of what is going on in that file. (And I want the html file; I am not looking for an alternative like just printing to pdf.)

If anyone can provide some pointers/direct me to a resource that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try offline browsers..... where you can download the hole content of the website  and you can read it as offline.

Comment: I was unsure what you meant by "offline browsers" but a quick search showed up HTTrack as an example. In fact, I had already tried using HTTrack. After getting it to use my proper login info to access the site (I am positive I did this right), the resulting html file looks the same as when I download straight from Firefox: ie no "middle" content. On inspection of the html code, however, the relevant content lines (analogous to 395 to 408) are not even there, so HTTrack is not even getting that code. Maybe this will help elucidate what is going on with that code...?

Comment: UPDATE:
After looking at the downloaded .html file and comparing it to one downloaded from a sister website (cookscountry.com) that works and displays perfectly fine, I noticed that the "middle content" is littered with these "data-reactid" attributes, while the one from the other website does not. Looking online, this has something to do with ReactJS. I don't know enough to know what this is, but could it be the root of the problem? If so, how can I solve it and download a working html copy?